# Shopify + Parallax Theme, How to target schema elements on home page

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

Okay, so I'm using shopify to build a website for a client. They bought a theme and want me to use it, but I want to still supply my client with a website that looks unique and not like another store with the same theme.

The main page allows you this customization side bar on the left where you can pick elements and put them on the page. This is what the home page html looks like:

```html
<div class="index-sections">
  {{ content_for_index }}
</div>
```

So there really isn't anywhere for me to put custom html/css in between elements. To be honest, I'd love to figure out how to split it up into sections but I haven't yet.

Shopify uses schema to pull whatever options you choose for lets say headers, or menu font, and applies them across the entire site. I've chosen a white font for the "headline" class, which means that any picture with text on it gets white font regardless of whether or not you can see it.

In this particular case, I want to change the font color because the majority of one of the photos I am using is white. I found the div id of the specific block of code that I need to style,

[Link to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh3qa.jpg)

I am just not sure how to target the headline class within it specifically. I tried :

```css
.shopify-section-1503016104719 headline{
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

Here is the website link https://luckyleo-dancewear-alt.myshopify.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the CSS element tag

```
.subtitle p {
    pointer-events: none;
    //color: black;
}
```

Comment: the .headline class will change every .headline on the page. I need to figure out how to single out the specific section created,  it's the picture of the item of clothing and watercolors against the white background.

Comment: Just use  .subtitle p

Answer (score 0):

I have Parallax. You can add custom HTML to the home page via the "custom HTML" option, after clicking "Add A Section" in the theme editor (where you do the drag and drop styling). If you don't have sections, make sure the theme is the most recent version as this is a "pre-section-era" theme. You can also use custom HTML in the page editor.

Have you considered adding options for choosing a color within the actual sections files/schemas so that you can choose individual sections for each header?